# Restoring Database SQL Server - data is null this method or property cannot be called on null values

Tags: sql-server, database, null, dbnull

I am trying to copy 2 databases from SQL Server 2012 to a new VM SQL Server 2017.

One of the databases was restored successfully but the other is giving me the below issues.

Databases both restored successfully, however 1 of the databases when I try to access the tables I am getting this error in SSMS "data is null this method or property cannot be called on null values"

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You are going to have to provide some context here. We haven't been working on this project and have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I have 2 databases on SQL 2012 which I need to restore on SQL 2017. 1 Database restored successfully and all tables accessible. The other database when I try to access the tables folder I am getting that error.

Comment: You mean in SSMS?

Comment: @SeanLange yes.

Comment: How do your mdf and ldf files look? Can you check both of those values for the two restored databases? Maybe validate the physical size of those files, and locations, are correct.

Comment: Have you upgraded your SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2017 has numerous features that aren't present in SQL Server 2012 and it is likely your version of SSMS doesn't support the newer version of SQL Server.

It's probable that when you open the database in SSMS it is trying to load Database Diagrams (now deprecated).

Are you able to run:

```
USE [databasename]
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

and see if your expected tables are in there?